# Why planes do not fall?

Tags: stochastic-processes, recreational-mathematics, mathematical-modeling, stochastic-analysis

**COVER STORY**

Suppose, I have an infinite metro line with an infinite number of stations.

Let single car occupancy be $n \cdot k$, and we let up to $n$ people leave and enter at each station. For each person entering the car we draw a destination station to be one of the $k$ **next** stations uniformly at random.  People with destination at current station leave the car.

I want to ensure, that there are **at most** $n$ people destined at the next station in the car, i.e. I don't want anyone to miss her respective station.

Suppose, I have calculated the probability for this successful outcome for station numbered $m$, and the probability is $p$. I'm pretty sure $p < 1$.

What makes me worry, is if I look at (possibly) independent events "all passengers to station $m$ successfully left", "all passengers to station $m+k$ successfully left", etc. This is in some sense a geometric random variable, and undoubtedly some will "succeed", i.e. not all passengers could leave at some station.

**ESSENCE**

But the same kind of idea is applied by airlines, when I make an online seat reservation. My weight is never asked (for at least 150+ passengers flights), nor the weight of kids, or other relatives. Nonetheless, I suppose the airline expects the weight of each row, or more critically the blocks of rows to be "equally" distributed throughout the plane.

Since, there are possible passenger arrangements, which assign all the light passengers, let say, to the front and all the heavier passengers to the back, I deduce the probability of successful passenger assignment $p$ is also less than $1$. I.e. after some finite number of assignments some plane should be loaded in some wrong way.

> Why airlines do not seem to worry?

Comment: I think the title is not very describing of the problem. Mass distribution does not immediately lead into planes falling off the sky.

Comment: How sensitive is the flight of a large passenger plane to the distribution of passenger weights? I don’t know the answer to that question, but I suspect the answer to your question is that amongst all airline crashes which were investigated, passenger weight distribution hasn’t been identified as a cause.

Comment: I'm guessing planes have sensors that detect if they are dangerously imbalanced, and when that happens, the crew would just rearrange the passengers.

Comment: @Joe Actually, there was a crash that was caused by a combination of overweight and a mechanical failure. And the distribution of the weight also played a role in this case. But what has to be considered is that the weight was only estimated, not actually determined. This has been changed, now the weight is determined exactly, at least for small planes that can be vulnerable to such effects.

Comment: See [Aircraft Weight & Balance Control](https://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/handbooks_manuals/aviation/media/faa-h-8083-1.pdf).

Comment: @Mauro ALLEGRANZA, quoting: If the actual seating location of each passenger is not known, the operator may assume that all passengers are seated uniformly throughout the cabin or a specified subsection of the cabin.

So it is kind of what I ask, the manual just say **assume**, but how they know?

Comment: From a strictly mathematical point of view, having $p<1$ isn't necessarily reason to worry.  It could be that $p = 1 - 10^{-50}$ or something like that, meaning it's very unlikely to happen even if there were a million flights per second from now until the sun goes out.  Managing risk involves not only considering what hazards are *possible*, but which are *probable* enough to be worth worrying about.

Comment: @Joe, https://www.theguardian.com/world/2014/sep/03/qantas-flight-struggles-to-take-off-as-child-passengers-tip-balance

Comment: That article definitely suggests that weight distribution can be important, but I still suspect that the variation in adult weight hasn’t caused any crashes that we know of, which is why “airlines do not seem to worry.” Whether they should be worried is another question, but I suspect that’s why they don’t. Now, if it’s actually true that every year there are a few large passenger aircraft that crash, with investigations showing that it was because of passenger weight distribution, but airlines still do not worry, that would be surprising to find out.